# Can Mac OSX Lion receive push notifications while the computer is asleep?

Tags: macos, apple-push-notifications, osx-lion

Can Mac OSX Lion receive push notifications while the computer is asleep? Is it possible to use this method to wake the computer up from sleep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for push notifications to be received the machine has to be connected to the greater internet, and keeping the network up would require a significant amount of energy (especially over wifi.) Wake-on-lan, on the other hand, only listens for local packets over ethernet without even needing a higher level stack such as TCP/IP, so it requires very low energy, comparable to the same energy needed to keep the RAM alive while the machine is asleep.